# upgrading rails 4 to rails 6 - directly or step by step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to upgrade the rails 4 app to rails 6 latest version. To do so, should I upgrade directly from 4 to 6 or have to do step by step ?

First Rails 4 to Rails 5, then 5.0 to 5.2, then 5.2 to 6.0, then 6.0 to latest version ?

Current Rails version - 4.2, Ruby - 2.3.6

And what version is best suitable for Rails 5.0 & Rails 5.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5.0 and 5.2, you could go for Ruby 2.7 or 3.0 version.

If you want to upgrade your rails app from rails 4 to rails 6, then I would suggest you to create a new rails 6 app and migrate all your files. Because in Rails 6 there are a lot of new changes like webpacker, new Javascript file structure etc.

Comment: I guess for Rails 5.0 we should use Ruby less than 2.5. But not sure which should be the right one.

Comment: And if we are migrating from Rails 4 - 6, then should we create a new project ?

Comment: For Rails 5.0 - compatible ruby versions are >= 2.2.2 and < 2.5.0.
And for Rails 5.2 - compatible ruby versions are >= 2.2.2 and < 2.6.0.

For Rails 6.0 - compatible ruby versions are >= 2.5.0 and < 3.0.0.

Comment: I have not tried this. But If you are to move from rails 4 to 6 then I would suggest you creating a new application/project.